# Does GHC removes polymorphic indirection when possible?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghc

```
showInt :: Int -> String
showInt x = show x
```

Does the above code calls `show` passing the `Int` dictionary or does it calls directly the function declared on `Show Int` instance?

I mean, does GHC removes polymorphic indirection from generated code when possible?

Comment: It will often do, as shown by hammar, and sometime not. Therefore, the more general question is : "What situations prevent GHC from optimizing away the dictionnary indirection ?" . I know some situations involving extensions, but IIRC there are also such cases in Haskell 98, maybe with polymorphic recursive functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. This is the generated core using GHC 7.4.2:

```
Foo.showInt :: GHC.Types.Int -> GHC.Base.String
[... attributes omitted ...]
Foo.showInt = GHC.Show.$fShowInt_$cshow
```

As you can see, it's just a direct reference to `GHC.Show.$fShowInt_$cshow`.

Compare with what happens if we remove the type signature so that the inferred type `Show a => a -> String` is used instead:

```
Foo.showInt
  :: forall a_aop. GHC.Show.Show a_aop => a_aop -> GHC.Base.String
[... attributes omitted ...]
Foo.showInt =
  \ (@ a_aot) ($dShow_aou :: GHC.Show.Show a_aot) (x_a9Z :: a_aot) ->
    GHC.Show.show @ a_aot $dShow_aou x_a9Z
```

Here, it takes a dictionary argument `$dShow_aou` and it uses the accessor function `GHC.Show.show` to look
up the appropriate function from this dictionary before applying the resulting function to the argument `x_a9Z`.

What happens in the first case, at least conceptually, is that since the concrete type is known, GHC inserts a direct reference to the appropriate instance dictionary rather than taking it as an argument. Then, the accessor, which is basically just a record label, can be inlined and you're left
with a direct reference to the appropriate function.

Answer (score -7):

GHC doesn't do that. Think of a new created type for readibility:

```
type Vector = (Float, Float)
```

If GHC would removes Polymorphicism from a function like:

```
(!+!) :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
(x1, y1) !+! (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
```

The type would become:

```
(!+!) :: (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float)
```

While the function is ment for Vector's specifically.

Comment: The declaration `type Vector = (Float, Float)` means that the type `Vector` and the type `(Float, Float)` are exactly the same, and your function has both the type `Vector -> Vector -> Vector` and the type `(Float, Float) -> (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float)` because they mean the same, so no, that's not correct.

Comment: When generating code GHC specializes polymorphic functions where possible, generating more efficient versions at known types. Inlining can also be used to resolve indirection.